# What should one meditate upon as a beginner?

Tags: meditation

I am planning to start meditation.

As a beginner , what things I should meditate upon from the Buddha's perspective?

Comment: [This](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=gM8YDQAAQBAJ&pg=PT343&lpg=PT343&dq=meditate+on+love+pity+joy+impurity+serenity+buddha&source=bl&ots=K2zrlhZST_&sig=_HpLmLFn-t84vTK_JEW-YRp-1GQ&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjepfiw9dTWAhXBr48KHdNRCdUQ6AEIOzAI#v=onepage&q=meditate%20on%20love%20pity%20joy%20impurity%20serenity%20buddha&f=false) book says mediate on Love , Joy ,Pity ,Impurity and Serenity. That looks pretty straightforward to me.

Answer (score 4):

That's like asking "what should I eat".

If liking to taste, here are the 40 meals, or better working places: [Kammaṭṭhāna](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kamma%E1%B9%AD%E1%B9%ADh%C4%81na)

For which one might be good for your tendency it would be best to look after a skilled meditation teacher but generally the ten recollections, best starting from below (and develope proper perception for them) are fine for one living at home, as well as the Brahma-viharas, later on.

What ever might be pleasing for the mind to go with it best possible without much laps.

> I am just a beginner...Just give me high priority 4-5 things to meditate upon.

First three recollections are of the virtues of the Three Jewels:

- (1) Buddha
- (2) Dharma
- (3) Sangha

Next three are recollections of the virtues of:

- (4) morality (Śīla)
- (5) liberality (cāga)

Suttas in regard of them: [Recollections](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#recollections)

It would be good to ask first and likewise for [Refuge](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#tiratana) and for the [precepts](http://www.zugangzureinsicht.org/html/index-subject_en.html#precepts) first, taking them, best from a Monk or Nun, Dheeraj Verma.

(If having no access, but serious and having patient, one might be always [welcome for such](http://sangham.net/index.php/topic,1042.0.html#post_eng) online.)

Mudita & Anumodana

*[Note: This is a gift of Dhamma and not meant for commercial purpose or other gains in the world]*

Comment: I am just a beginner...Just give me high priority 4-5 things to meditate upon.

Answer (score 2):

There are different types of meditation.

For basic insight meditation based on the mindfulness of breathing, you can consider starting with [Yuttadhammo Bhikkhu](http://buddhistinsights.com/yuttadhammo-bhikkhu/)'s "How To Meditate" series for beginners, which is available as a [YouTube video playlist](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL603BD0B03E12F5A1) or as an [online booklet](https://www.sirimangalo.org/text/how-to-meditate/). This meditation is based on the four foundations of mindfulness. It comes in the varieties of sitting and walking meditation.

[Thanissaro Bhikkhu](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanissaro_Bhikkhu)'s "[A Guided Meditation](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/guided.html)" and "[Basic Breath Meditation Instructions](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/lib/authors/thanissaro/breathmed.html)" instruction sets combine mindfulness of breathing with body scanning (or sweeping). There's an audio version of these instructions in [this YouTube video](https://youtu.be/aDuLn-Kj93c). This meditation is quite suitable for beginners. I like the fact that it begins with some thoughts of loving kindness (metta) before proceeding to the rest of the meditation.